# Mapbox 4 to Mapbox 5 errors

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I have been trying to to upgrade from Mapbox 4.x.x to Mapbox 5.x.x. It compiles and the app runs, but on the instance creation of Mapbox it crashes with the following errors:

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LostLocationEngine>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mapzen/android/lost/api/LostApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;
I/art:     at java.util.Map com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngineProvider.obtainDefaultLocationEnginesDictionary() (LocationEngineProvider.java:54)
I/art:     at void com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngineProvider.initAvailableLocationEngines(android.content.Context) (LocationEngineProvider.java:40)
I/art:     at void com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngineProvider.<init>(android.content.Context) (LocationEngineProvider.java:23)
I/art:     at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (Mapbox.java:54)
I/art:     at void com.studentservices.lostoncampus.AnalyticsApplication.onCreate() (AnalyticsApplication.java:45)
I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(android.app.Application) (Instrumentation.java:1032)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5881)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1718)
I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6688)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1468)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1358)
I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mapzen.android.lost.api.LostApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.studentservices.lostoncampus-1/s
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/art:     at java.util.Map com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngineProvider.obtainDefaultLocationEnginesDictionary() (LocationEngineProvider.java:54)
I/art:     at void com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngineProvider.initAvailableLocationEngines(android.content.Context) (LocationEngineProvider.java:40)
I/art:     at void com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngineProvider.<init>(android.content.Context) (LocationEngineProvider.java:23)
I/art:     at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) (Mapbox.java:54)
I/art:     at void com.studentservices.lostoncampus.AnalyticsApplication.onCreate() (AnalyticsApplication.java:45)
I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(android.app.Application) (Instrumentation.java:1032)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5881)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1718)
I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6688)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1468)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I have the following Mapbox dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.4.0'

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.3.0'
```

I am not really too sure what is going on. I have tried clean building, enabling multi-dex and invalidating the cache/restrarting without any luck any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Seems to work if I add -

```
implementation "com.mapzen.android:lost:3.0.2"
```

Comment: Thanks! It did work for me

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I suspect that whatever "com.mapzen.android:lost:3.0.2" was resolving to in 2016 isn't at that location anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least a missing dependency to be included:

```
implementation "com.mapzen.android:lost:3.0.2"
```

Comment: For an explanation of the general, underlying issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35751439/1813403

Answer (score 0):

```
For Android Studio 3.0.1

You Can use This Lib. Also

 implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.9.0'
    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.9.0') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.3.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true

    }
    enter code here
```