# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/PacProcessor

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Can't really find words, my project just don't compile from one day to another.

This is what I do:

I download and show a PDF, later I print it as a saved PDF to the device, then the crash comes.

**Here is the crash:**

```
at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
   at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:176)
   at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:459)
   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:251)
   at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2681)
   at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2676)
   at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2741)
   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4815)
   at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4956)
   at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:659)
   at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:659)
   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:604)
   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:587)
   at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:574)
   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
   at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:720)
   at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:788)
```

---

**(The actual error is so long that I cannot post it in stackoverflow, and none of it is my own code, it has problems with Android's webview.)**

---

**Here is the activity's code where the crash happens:**

```java
public class ActivityPrintSurvey extends ActivityBase implements MVPView, View.OnClickListener, SendScannedSignedDocumentTask.SendScannedSignedDocumentCallback {
    
    Document document;
    Patient patient;
    SurveyBundle surveyBundle;

    View hider;
    Button printBtn;
    Button backBtn;
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Switch switcher;

    boolean canPrint = false;

    PrintManager printManager;
    String jobName;

    String fileName;

    String pdfUrl;
    String showPdfUrl;
    private int SIGNING_DONE_1 = 105;

    int runnableCounter = 0;
    final int RUNNABLE_MAX = 3;

    private void log(Object o) {

        Log.i("PRINTING_ACT", o.toString());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_print_survey);


        log("activity started");

        hider = findViewById(R.id.hider);
        printBtn = findViewById(R.id.print_btn);
        backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        switcher = findViewById(R.id.read_and_accepted_switch);


        document = (Document) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("document");
        patient = (Patient) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("patient");
        surveyBundle = (SurveyBundle) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("survey_bundle");

        jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
        printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        printBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


        showPDF();
    }


    private void showPDF() {

        log("starting to show pdf");

        pdfUrl = document.getPdfUrl();

        String embedUrl = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=";
        showPdfUrl = embedUrl + pdfUrl;

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (runnableCounter < RUNNABLE_MAX) {
                    runnableCounter++;
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadUrl(showPdfUrl);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    //Szörnyűséges a helyzet, az android szemét használhatatlan webview nem mindig jeleníti meg a pdf-et, ezért rá kell frissíteni párszor, hogy biztos megjelenítse, ez van.
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    hider.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        };
        handler.post(runnable);
        downloadPDF();
    }


    public void downloadPDF() {

        log("starting to download pdf");

        fileName = FileHelper.generateTempFileName();

        ANRequest.DownloadBuilder downloadBuilder = AndroidNetworking.download(pdfUrl, FileHelper.getTempFileDirectory(this), fileName);
        downloadBuilder.doNotCacheResponse();
        ANRequest request = downloadBuilder.build();

        request.setDownloadProgressListener(new DownloadProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long totalBytes) {
                // do anything with progress
                Log.i("ON_PROGRESS", bytesDownloaded + " / " + totalBytes);

            }
        }).startDownload(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadComplete() {
                // do anything after completion
                canPrint = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ANError error) {
                // handle error
                Toast.makeText(ActivityPrintSurvey.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void print() {

        log("starting to print");

        printManager.print(jobName, new PrintDocumentAdapter() {


            @Override
            public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;

                log("onWrite() called for printing");

                try {

                    File file = FileHelper.readTempFile(ActivityPrintSurvey.this, fileName);

                    input = new FileInputStream(file);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;

                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});
                    log("onWriteFinished() called for printing");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Catch exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    log("Exception 1: " + e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    try {
                        input.close();
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        log("Exception 2: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {
                log("onLayout() done");

                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    callback.onLayoutCancelled();
                    log("onLayoutCancelled()");
                    return;
                }

                PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(fileName/*Ez itt lehet bármi, kiskutya füle, nem kell megegyeznie az alap file nevvel*/).setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();
                callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
                log("onLayoutFinished() called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                FileHelper.deleteTempFiles(ActivityPrintSurvey.this);

                log("onFinish() done");

                // ha kész a nyomtatás, jöhet a valós aláírás tollal, majd visszafotózás, és feltöltés

                new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityPrintSurvey.this)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.next_step))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.please_scan_the_printed_and_signed_document))
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.scan), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                startScanningByCameraPhoto();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            }
                        })
                        .show();

                log("showing alert dialog");

            }
        }, null);
    }

    public void startScanningByCameraPhoto() {

        // start picker to get image for cropping and then use the image in cropping activity
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .start(this);

        log("startScanningByCameraPhoto");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        log("onActivityResult called");

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SIGNING_DONE_1) {

                log("RESULT_OK from SIGNING_DONE_1 -> calling .finish()");

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("document", document);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            log("1. Error: resultCode NOT RESULT OK");
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                log("RESULT_OK from CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE");

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                File file = new File(resultUri.getPath());

                showLoading();

                SendScannedSignedDocumentTask task = new SendScannedSignedDocumentTask(this, this, DatabaseHelper.getInstance().readLoggedInUser().getUserToken(), document, patient, file);
                task.execute();

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                log("2. Error: resultCode NOT RESULT OK: " + error.getMessage());
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void handleUploadScannedDocumentAPIDone(String error) {

        hideLoading();

        if (error != null) {
            log("handleUploadScannedDocumentAPIDone, error:" + error);
            DialogHelper.showInfo(this, error);
        } else {
            log("handleUploadScannedDocumentAPIDone -> finishing()");
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            Toast.makeText(this, "✔ " + getString(R.string.uploaded), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.equals(printBtn)) {

            if (switcher.isChecked()) {
                if (canPrint) {
                    print();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF not found in device. Retrying download...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    downloadPDF();
                }
            } else {
                DialogHelper.showInfo(this, getString(R.string.please_check_the_checkbox));
            }

        } else if (v.equals(backBtn)) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void hideLoading() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void showLoading() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void showError(String error, String code) {
        hideLoading();
        canPrint = false;
        DialogHelper.showError(this, error);
        log("showing error: " + error);
    }


    @Override
    public void showSuccess(Object... object) {

        hideLoading();

        String api = object[0].toString();

        if (api.equals("eject_patient")) {

            log("showSuccess: " + "finishing activity.");

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityWaitingForPatient.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        } else {
            log("showSuccess: " + "ERROR: " + api + " not equals " + "eject_patient");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LayoutTextSizeChanger.changeAllTextSizeInLayout((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_cont), FontUtil.loadFontSize(this));

        log("onResume()"  );
    }


}
```

Comment: can you please show the build.gradle file? it might be that one of the libs is broken and you have + sign in the gradle

Comment: The same for me after obfuscation

Comment: Can you provide a github link so that we could run it locally to check if we can help?

Comment: that's why you never should rely on webview in your applications. they can update it at any time. so suddenly working code could break one day.

Comment: @Adam Varhegyi Did you find the cause of this problem?

Comment: @flauschtrud No. It just gone from one day to another...

Answer (score 14):

I'm experiencing the same exception and immense stack trace when using WebView in my app at runtime, depending on the software versions installed on the device:

Chrome Versions:

- 96.0.4664.92 / .104 - ok, no errors
- 97.0.4692.98 - errors, see below

Android Versions:

- Android 7 -> NoClassDefFoundError for `android.webkit.TracingController`
- Android 9 -> NoClassDefFoundError for `android.webkit.PacProcessor`
- Android 12 -> no such errors

According to your description and stack trace, you see this error at runtime, not at compile time, right? So, I would recommend to

- test on an Android 12 target or
- install an older Chrome version

Comment: This sounds like the case here. I get the PacProcessor error in Android device running version 9, chrome version 101.0.4951.41. Android 11 with the same chrome version - no errors.
How can I overcome the error in the Android 9 device?

Comment: but how to fix it please?..

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I can confirm this as well. Running Android 9 (SDK 28) and Chrome v66, I have no issues. Updated Chrome to v108 and now getting the PacProcessor error.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. On an Android 8.1 device, this started only after upgrading `Chrome` a few hours ago to version **110.0.5481.65**. Once uninstalled updates (reverted back to 71.0.3578.99), the problem disappeared.

Comment: Me too!!! After I **downgraded chrome** from 110 to 70(For this Just I clicked delete button in playstore.), the error is not occurred. 
  
But I don't think it is good solution.... Because there may be **security vulnerabilities** or **codebugs** depending on the version.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm... intermittent problem that references class loader issues. + a huge stack trace.

What little evidence you provided may point to silent IO-type errors.

Say for example the android you're using is dynamically loading classes at runtime and for some reason the host folder for whatever jars it's trying to use also contains that pdf file which is actively written to / read from ... or for whatever reason, that entire fileSystem partition is marked as locked.

In that case you'd wind up with intermittent class loader errors like the one you referenced.

also this:

```
try {
    input.close(); <--- if exception occurs at this point, output will never close.
    output.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    log("Exception 2: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

... I don't know... there's very little information to go by to be honest. For example you didn't post the content of the `finish()` routine, and that stack trace contains no references to your code (that i can see at least)... so this is kind of a wild stab in the dark.